# What is a "hanging node" in the finite element meshing?

Tags: finite-element, mesh-generation

When reading literatures about finite element method, the term "hanging nodes" can often be encountered. Could anyone tell me what indeed is a hanging node?

Comment: See page 3 in http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~omar/papers/cmes05.pdf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following picture illustrates a mesh with a hanging node and a mesh containing no hanging node:

[image]

Usually with a finite element mesh the vertices are shared with their other neighbouring elements, but the circled node does not belong to the bottom triangle. We call this node a hanging node. This commonly occurs during the process of adaptive mesh refinement. Hanging nodes are either removed - as is done in the above picture by connecting it to another vertex and thus creating two new elements - or by imposing constraints on the system.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Could you please suggest some papers or books regarding the treatment of hanging nodes, or the treatment of non-conforming elements?

Comment: @David406 Hanging node are usually removed by creating new elements - as is done in the above picture - or constraints are imposed on the system. I have only removed hanging nodes during adaptive refinement. I highly recommend Wolfgang Bangerth's video [tutorials](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bangerth/videos.html). They contain the info you are looking for in lecture 14-17?? and much much more!